# How to bind WCF methods to arbitrary URIs

Tags: c#, wcf

I use WCF (by means of using the WebChannelFactory) to invoke some services that are outside of my control, implemented in a variety of technologies. From the WCF perspective, my interface only has one method, let's call it "get-stuff". So, the same method can be implemented by these services as http://www.service-a.com/get-stuff, or as http://www.service-b.com/my-goodies/, or as http://www.service-c.com/retrieve-thing.php

In all examples I've seen the method binding to a particular URI is accomplished via the UriTemplate member of the WebGet/WebInvoke attribute. But this means, all the URIs for the "get-stuff" method must follow a fixed template. For, example, I can create a UriTemplate = "/get-stuff", so that my method will always be bound to /get-stuff.

However, I want my method to bind to any arbitrary URI. BTW, the parameters are passed as a POST data, so I do not need to worry about binding URI to parameters of the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have found a solution to the problem, by patching the UriTemplate of the WebInvokeAttribute at run-time. My single-method WCF interface is:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface IGetStuff
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    ResponseData GetStuff(RequestData request);
}
```

Here is how I get the handle to the interface:

```
//Find the last portion of the URI path
var afterLastPathSepPos = uri.LastIndexOf('/', uri.Length - 2) + 1;
var contractDesc = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IGetStuff));

foreach (var b in contractDesc.Operations[0].Behaviors)
{
    var webInvokeAttr = b as WebInvokeAttribute;

    if (webInvokeAttr != null)
    {
        //Patch the URI template to use the last portion of the path
        webInvokeAttr.UriTemplate = uri.Substring(afterLastPathSepPos, uri.Length - afterLastPathSepPos);
        break;
    }
}

var endPoint = new ServiceEndpoint(contractDesc, new WebHttpBinding(), new EndpointAddress(uri.Substring(0, afterLastPathSepPos)));

using (var wcf = new WebChannelFactory<I>(endPoint))
{
    var intf = wcf.CreateChannel();
    var result = intf.GetStuff(new RequestData(/*Fill the request data here*/));   //Voila!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you do something like this

```
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("any service url");
ChannelFactory<IMyService> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(binding, endpointAddress);
IMyServiceclient = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
client.GetStuff();
```

Comment: I believe the method GetStuff() will be called on the URI <any service url>/get-stuff according to the UriTemplate. What I want is to call the method GetStuff() just on <any service url>, without any fixed template.

Comment: As far as I know, you connect to the service itself, not to the method. Service is exposed at the URL that depends on server code. It doesn't have any method name. After you create the channel, you may call any method shared by the interface.

Comment: Not really, there is no concept of connecting to a service. When a remote web method is called via WCF, all that happens is that an HTTP request gets routed to a particular listener, which then responds. The implementations can be as simple as a static webpage, a WCF service, a PHP service, a node-JS, ASP.NET, or anything else for that matter.